# "Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()" when trying to run phpMyAdmin 4.2.7 on IIS 8 with PHP 5.4.30

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

I have PHP 5.4.30 installed and running well using the FastCGI module and IIS 8 (on Windows 8.1). I have MySQL installed and would like to manage it with phpMyAdmin, however, I get this error whenever I try to access the page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

Many older threads I have seen suggest adding extensions to the php.ini, but in the later versions of php, the `php.ini` file becomes `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development`. Whenever I try to modify either of these files or create a php.ini file, I get an error 500 when trying to visit other php pages. I have also seen many solutions related to Xampp / Apache, but none of them seem to work in IIS 8 (that I have found).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: then look at your server's error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: the most detail I can get from the logs is that it was a 500.0 error, which is "Module or ISAPI error occurred." according to Microsoft. Any suggestions on what to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the php_mbstring.dll file installed. You can find it on the [PHP Windows Extensions page](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)

Comment: The page you linked says that you need to add the extension to the php.ini file, but which one should I do it to; php.ini-production or php.ini-development? It seems that the php documentation isn't updated for the change in ini files yet.

Comment: Use phpinfo(); and see which loaded configuration file is loaded

Comment: According to phpinfo, no configuration files are loaded ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/aAxwb/af5619f2a9.png)) Do I need to rename php.ini-production or development to just php.ini?

Comment: In most WAMP stacks, you typically put the DLL into the proper directory and then uncomment the line in `php.ini` The files you mentioned are included as "starter" files. The real `php.ini` will be named just that.

Comment: I have renamed my `php.ini-production` file to `php.ini`, set my extension directory, and added the mbstring extension to `php.ini` (already had it downloaded). Now I get an error 500.0 on any PHP page I visit, including my `phpinfo()` page. The only solution I have found is reinstalling php, which leaves me with the same problems as before.